# Prove the equality of two concatenations of words

Tags: formal-languages

Let $x$, $u$, $v$, $w$, $y$, $x'$, $u'$, $v'$, $w'$, $y'$ be words. If

1. $y'x' = xy$
2. $y'u'x' = xuy$
3. $y'v'x' = xvy$
4. $y'w'x' = xwy$
5. $y'v'u'x' = xuvy$
6. $y'w'v'x' = xvwy$

all hold, then I need to prove that $y'w'v'u'x' = xuvwy$.

I'm a little confused how to prove this, How can I form $y'w'v'u'x'$ from the equations above?

Comment: What do you not understand? Note that if there is *no* set of suitable words, then the implication you are supposed to prove *is true*.

Comment: @Raphael why closed? The question is well-formed and clear to my eyes.

Comment: @RanG. It's a problem dump. ForSol does not state what they don't understand (the problem statement seems clear to me, indeed) nor what particular problem they face in finding a solution. In other words, there's not question here.

Comment: I've edited my question. Basically I do not know how to form y'w'v'u'x'

Comment: @Raphael ForSol did state their difficulty: starting with y'w'v'u'x', pattern matching doesn't reveal any further rule that can be applied.

Comment: I've posted an extension to this problem, [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/32618/show-that-a-regular-language-l-consists-purely-of-palindromes-if-and-only-if).

Answer (score 5):

Suppose without loss of generality that $|y'| \geq |x|$. If we write $y' = xa$ then $ax' = y$. The equalities then become

1. $xau'x' = xuax'$.
2. $xav'x' = xvax'$.
3. $xaw'x' = xwax'$.
4. $xav'u'x' = xuvax'$.
5. $xaw'v'x' = xvwax'$.

Cancelling $x,x'$, we get

1. $au' = ua$.
2. $av' = va$.
3. $aw' = wa$.
4. $av'u' = uva$.
5. $aw'v' = vwa$.

Using $y' = xa$, (5), (1), and $y = ax'$, we get
$$ y'w'v'u'x' = xaw'v'u'x' = xvwau'x' = xvwuax' = xvwuy. $$
This is close to what we want, only we got $vwu$ instead of $uvw$.

Plugging (2) into (4) gives $uva = av'u = vau' = vua$, and so $u$ and $v$ commute. Similarly, plugging (2) into (5) gives $vwa = aw'v' = wav'=wva$, and so $v$ and $w$ commute. The set of words commuting with $v$ forms a commutative monoid (since all are powers of some primitive word), and so $u$ and $w$ also commute. Therefore $vwu = uvw$, completing the proof.