# Prove $y'w'v'u'x' = xuvwy$

Tags: word-combinatorics

This question repeats [one that was closed](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/32583/prove-ywvux-xuvwy).

Let $x, u, v, w, y, x', u', v', w', y'$ be words satisfying

1. $y'x' = xy$.
2. $y'u'x' = xuy$.
3. $y'v'x' = xvy$.
4. $y'w'x' = xwy$.
5. $y'v'u'x' = xuvy$.
6. $y'w'v'x' = xvwy$.

Show that $y'w'v'u'x' = xuvwy$.